# Zend Framework - Getting access to controller and action names in resource class (inherits after Zend_Controller_Resource_ResourceAbstract)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I need to create my own resource which sends some information to `Zend_View` instance which depends on currently working controller and action.
I've got this code:

```
$view = $bootstrap->getResource('layout')->getView();
$front = $bootstrap->getResource('frontController');
$front->setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http);

$controller = $front->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $front->getRequest()->getActionName();

$view->headTitle(
    $this->getPage()
        ->setController($controller)
        ->setAction($action)
        ->getTitle()
);
```

but `$controller` and `$action` are empty. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or getting access to controller and action names is impossible in resource.

Comment: I wonder if its because you are overwriting the request that was there, when you call `$front->setRequest();` . Try moving your `$controller` & `$action` lines above the `setRequest()`

Comment: I've tried it before I asked. If I don't set request object, it doesn't exist in Zend_Controller_Front instance.

Comment: Is the above the full script? If not can you post the rest of it?

Comment: It's full Resource class: http://ld2.kacperkolodziej.com/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the request object in a resource because it doesn't exist yet. The request object gets set during dispatch which happens after the application has been bootstrapped. It sounds like this logic should be moved to a controller plugin instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked `Zend_Controller_Front` on the Zend API Docs and I have seen `dispatch` function which needs `Zend_Controller_Action_Abstract` argument, but I wasn't sure if there is any way to get access to names of controller and action.